# Accuracy of estimation of the variance

Tags: statistics, variance

Consider $N$ i.i.d. samples $x_1, \dots, x_N$ from an unknown discrete distribution on $\{0,\dots, n\}$. We know that

$$\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i = 1}^N (x_i - m)^2$$

where $m$ is the sample mean, is an unbiased estimator for the variance.

But what confidence intervals can we give for this estimate?

Comment: If $s^2=\frac{1}{N-1} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N (x_i - m)^2$ then $\frac{(N-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$

Comment: I wouldn't say that $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are samples; rather I would say that the tuple, or maybe the multiset, $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ is a sample. Just one sample, consisting of $N$ observations. That is why one speaks of $N$ as the $\text{“sample size”.} \qquad$

Comment: @Henry : That is true if $x_i$ are normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2,$ but this is a different distribution. Read the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the asymptotic approximation. Specifically, there is enough structure to invoke the CLT, i.e., letting $S_n^2$ denote the sample variance ($n$ here denotes the sample size),
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(X_i-\mathsf{E}X_i)^2-\sigma^2\right]+o_p(1)\\
&\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\sigma^2(\kappa-1)),
\end{align}
where $\kappa:=\mu_4/\sigma^4$, $\mu_k$ is the $k$-th central moment of $X_1$, and $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$. Therefore, the asymptotic confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ (at nominal level $\alpha$) is of the form
$$
S_n^2\pm z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}S_n^2\sqrt{(K_n-1)/n},
$$ 
where $K_n$ is the sample kurtosis.

Comment: You have used $n$ for the sample size where the OP has $N$.  The variable $n$ is used to define the support of the discrete distribution.  What are $z_1$, $\alpha$ and $p$ in your answer?

Comment: Sure. But I stated that clearly in the first paragraph.

Comment: You did but I thought it might be clearer for the OP to use the same notation. Have you used somewhere that we know the variance is finite?

Comment: Capital $n$ would look ugly.

Comment: Blame the OP :). How about my other questions (I see you in fact defined $\alpha$)?

Comment: It is standard notation: $X_n=o_p(1)$ means that $X_n$ converges in prob. to $0$, $z_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-quantile of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you! It's always worth defining terms when answering a question from the general public.

Comment: This takes care of large samples, but what if you have to cope with a small sample?

Comment: @MichaelHardy In that case I'd use bootstrap.

Comment: Could you say more about the bootstrap idea?

Comment: @Anush The [idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) is to approximate the finite sample distribution of $S_n$ given data. In the i.i.d. case it is typically more accurate than the asymptotic approximation for small sample sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If the $X_i$ are i.i.d. normally distributed $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $s^2=\frac{1}{N-1} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ then $$\frac{(N-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{N-1}$$

so, for example, if you want a $95\%$ confidence interval for the variance then you could use something like $$\left[ \frac{(N-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.025,N-1}}, \frac{(N-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.975,N-1}} \right]$$

You may need other approaches if the $X_i$ are not normally distributed; if your underlying distribution was Binomial with known $n$ and unknown $p$, the normal approximation may be good enough with large $N$, or you could take a more specific approach

Comment: The OP mentioned the distribution is discrete and unknown but with a known range $\{0,\dots,n\}$.   How can your answer be applied in this case?

Comment: @Anush For large $N$, you have the central limit theorem to help the normal approximation